# Subclipse install crashes Eclipse without any message

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, subclipse

I run Eclipse Oxygen 2 on Ubuntu 16. Trying to install `Subclipse` plugin. Eclipse just crashes during installation without any message. How to find problem?

UPD.

Eclipse doesn't start anymore.

After several crashes currently I sometimes get messages box:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/local/jdk-9.0.1/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-jar /opt/oxygen2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/oxygen2//plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.7.2.20171218-0600/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/oxygen2/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/oxygen2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so
-startup /opt/oxygen2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 370004
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/local/jdk-9.0.1/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-jar /opt/oxygen2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

And .log file contains lines:

```
SESSION 2018-01-04 07:22:29.157 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171130-0510
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2 0 2018-01-04 07:23:07.398
!MESSAGE Enablement expression is missing for descriptor type org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.coreBuildDescriptorType

!ENTRY org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2 0 2018-01-04 07:23:07.724
!MESSAGE Enablement expression is missing for config provider for org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.coreBuildDescriptorType

!ENTRY org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2 0 2018-01-04 07:23:07.724
!MESSAGE Enablement expression is missing for config provider for org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.coreBuildDescriptorType
~
```

Comment: Any messages in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: Can you open eclipse from the terminal to at least get some output/error message ?

Comment: After some manipulation with workspace change Eclipse not starts anymore. More details in message body.

Answer (score 0):

From:

https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki

Subclipse is able to provide an Eclipse plugin for **Windows** that includes the needed native DLL's, so installation on Windows is easy. On Linux and Mac, due to differences in how library loading is handled, it is not possible to provide the libraries in a way that "just works".

You will have to install JavaHL on Linux.

see:

https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki/JavaHL-on-Linux

Comment: Did you also add the variables -vmargs
-Djava.library.path=</path/to/library> to your eclipse.ini? Consider also the part which says that you could run into problems because of different versions in the subversion library.

Comment: Yes, variables are there

Comment: The native JavaHL libraries missing would NOT cause Eclipse to crash.  You would just get an error within Eclipse that the libraries were not found and the SVN API would not be available.  I think to diagnose further some kind of log or error that points to the cause of the crash is needed.